# Confusion about recursive methods execution in java

Tags: java, recursion

I have one big recursive method and can't understand the execution. Suppose we have a recursive method as below:

```
  private void recursiveMethod(){
    //execute some code 1

    if(someValue){
        recursiveMethod();
    }

    //execute some other code 2
}
```

and the scenario:

1. call `recursiveMethod()`
2. if `someValue` true recall it
3. `someValue` becam false
4. must execute `code 2`

but after this scenario is done, there is a second `code 2` execution - probably from first method run, is that normal in recursive methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is normal. When the recursive call returns, it will continue execution after the recursive call. If you don't want this behaviour, you could return after the recursive call like this:

```
private void recursiveMethod(){
    //execute some code 1

    if(someValue){
        recursiveMethod();
        return;
    }

    //execute some other code 2
}
```

Comment: but if my recursiveMethod returns boolean instead of void, how can I use your method?

Comment: then you can return method it self. Like `if(someValue){
       return recursiveMethod();
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Normally add `return` after `someValue == true` (after recall to this method)